# Store Collection of Data Fields and Retrieve Via Identifier

Tags: c#, collections

In C#, how can I store a collection of values so if I want to retrieve a particular value later, I can do something like:

myCollection["Area1"].AreaCount = 50;

or

count = myCollection["Area1"].AreaCount;

Generic list?

I'd like to store more than one property to a "key". Is a class the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Based on your comment, it seems like you want a Dictionary (as already suggested) where your object holds all your 'values.'

For Instance:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int AreaCount;
   public string foo;
   public bool bar;
}

//Create dictionary to hold, and a loop to make, objects:
Dictionary<string, MyClass> myDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
while(condition)
{ 
   string name = getName(); //To generate the string keys you want
   MyClass mC = new MyClass();
   myDict.Add(name, mC);
}

//pull out yours and modify AreaCount
myDict["Area1"].Value.AreaCount = 50;
```

Alternatively, you could add a `string` "Name" to you class (I'm using fields for the example, you'd probably use properties)  and use Linq:

```
//Now we have a list just of your class (assume we've already got it)
myClass instanceToChange = (from items in myList
                          where Name == "Area1"
                          select item).FirstOrDefault();

myClass.AreaCount = 50;
```

Does that help more?

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE** 
I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but I'll give it ago.

Given a list of Objects from which you need to grab a particular object, there are (generally) 4 ways- depending on your specific needs.

The Generic `List<T>` really only does this well at all if your object already supports some kind of searching (like String.Contains()).

A [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) uses IComparer to compare and sort the Key values and arrange the list that way.

A [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) stores a Key and Value so that `KeyValuePair` objects can be retrieved.

A [HashTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(VS.71).aspx) uses Keys and Values where the Keys must implement `GetHashCode()` and `ObjectEquals`

The specific one you need will vary based on your specific requirements.

Comment: I'd like to store more than one property to a key. Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on if you're in .NET 4 or not.  If so, you can use a List<Tuple<TItem1, TItem2>> and treat TItem1 as your 'key.'  I haven't had to use SortedList or HashTable much, so maybe someone can lay me knowledge on those, but I know you can only have value for a given key in a Dictionary.  In .NET 3.5 or before, you'd probably have to write something...

Comment: See your edit. So I populate the fields of the class and then store the class along with the key into the dictionary

Comment: Yeah, basically.  YMMV, but this should get you pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`Dictionary<string, YourClass>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).  (Where `YourClass` has an `AreaCount` property)

Comment: Thank You SLaks for your always helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is provided by [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(VS.71).aspx)